# pygtk scrolledwindow background color

Tags: background, pygtk, scrolledwindow

I have the following code in my PyGTK application:

```
scroll = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
scroll.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_NEVER, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
scroll.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL,gtk.gdk.Color("#FFFFFF"))
scroll.add_with_viewport(self.movieView)

layout = gtk.VBox()
layout.pack_start(top,False,False)
layout.pack_start(scroll)
```

But the background of the scroll area still shows up gray, instead of white
Is this a known bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Likely you are seeing the background color of the `gtk.Viewport` or `self.movieView`, whatever that is.

Comment: self.movieView is a widget that extends gtk.VBox, so, changing the bg of the viewport should fix it?

Comment: @Dirk it's been a while since this question. did you ever find a fix though? I'm having the same trouble in C++.

Comment: Same trouble too